# Clean install of 14.04 over corrupted 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, dual-boot, partitioning

How can I put up a clean install of 14.04 on a dual boot machine with the "something else" option (manual partitions). It appears that when I try to clear the old partitions and re-partition it still pulls my old configuration (something in unity is appearing to cause errors) and causing me to have the same errors as before. Due to it being a dual boot machine I can't select "Erase and Install" as that would wipe my Windows boot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a "Remove all linux partitions" option, if so do that.  Otherwise, you will have to format the linux partitions manually and then install over that.

Comment: I didnt see a "remove all linux partitions" option. And I think I did manually format the linux partitions? If that's something other than what you do in the "something else" by first removing the old ones then re-partitioning please let me know.

Comment: You need to go to manual partitioning and format each linux partition, particularly the one mounted at `/`

Comment: You could even delete those partitions then reboot and select install alongside Windows

Comment: How do I do that? I guess another option would be wipe the disks from the windows install (I have 4 disks in my system, 2 for windows and 2 for ubuntu). Also, since they're on separate disks it has trouble detecting the windows install.

Comment: That will work, but inside the installer you can go to manual partitioning and just delete the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I did do that. I went into "Something Else" during install. Removed all partitions on sdc and sdd (ubuntu drives) then re-partitioned the drives manually. However, it still recognized that there was a previous ubuntu install there and pulled my configuration

Comment: Try formatting those drives in Windows, and then doing the install

Comment: Format them as NTFS or exFAT

Comment: Ok I'll try that when I get home. Any reason to pick exFAT over NTFS?

Comment: No, just to try to make it something foreign to the Linux installer.  It will be wiped by the installer so it doesn't matter

Comment: Ok sounds good, just one last question. What is the default format used by Ubuntu that it's changing to? My boot USB is Fat32. Will it use that?

Comment: Ubuntu likes to use EXT4